# Best Practice or method to see if the form changed from its initial values or not

Tags: eureka-forms

I apologize if this is covered elsewhere, but I haven't been able to find a reference to this.

Is there a built-in method or Best Practice to identifying which rows had changed from their initial values?

Comment: What you mean, what is your issue? please explain what you need so I can help you

Comment: I have a form that is editing an existing record. In my case, any edits to this record disable the record and create a new one. As such I don't want to create a new record if the user just opens it and hits save. So ideally I just want to go to the form and say "hasChanges" and if yes - we then iterate all the values. If not, we just dismiss.

Comment: I ussually do this having 2 models, one original and another with the modifications, then I put a method in the model comparing the values to check if was modified

Comment: Right - in traditional forms I can do that, but I can't create the model like that - this is CareKit which hides all the model logic and so on, and so you have to create the actual database entry in order to get a model you can compare against. The only correct way to do it here is to actually test each form value against its initial value. So I might write a protocol extension to do that. I think Eureka should have this built in- it makes sense there.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I ended up doing - and this has been working well. This is a partial class implementation just for this purpose:

```
class YourFormViewController : FormViewController {

var formValuesChanged = [String : (Any?, Any?)]()

override func valueHasBeenChanged(for row: BaseRow, oldValue: Any?, newValue: Any?) {
    super.valueHasBeenChanged(for: row, oldValue: oldValue, newValue: newValue)
    guard let rowIdentifier = row.tag else { return }
    formValuesChanged[rowIdentifier] = (oldValue, newValue)
}
```

}

I use this as a base class for all my forms and then I can just use:

```
        guard formValuesChanged.count > 0 else {
        log.info("Did not save editor because no values were changed")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
```